# Comparing column values using array - PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to find the best solution for this problem. I have a table (I simplified here with only two columns) in which I have to check if the 'customer_id' is the same for each 'service_id' that I can have in the table.

If the customer_id for the same service_id is different, the service_id is raised as warning. I created a loop to pick each single service_id and I tried to save the results of the select query as an array. The problem is the array I created seems not multidimensional (I can't get the 'customer_id' to make comparison).

I don't have a clear picture of how arrays work, so probably I'm doing something wrong. The table services is this one:

[image]

The code I have written so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE process_services()
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
   DECLARE     r RECORD;
   DECLARE     cur_row REFCURSOR;
   DECLARE services varchar array;
    begin
      
        OPEN cur_row FOR EXECUTE 'select distinct(service_id)
                                from services';
      loop
           FETCH NEXT FROM cur_row INTO r;
    -- exit when no more row to fetch
           EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
                
       SELECT array(select row(service_id, customer_id) FROM services WHERE service_id = r.service_id) INTO services;
       
       IF array_length(services, 1) < 2 THEN
          raise notice 'ERROR singleton, service_id =% ',r.service_id;
       -- check if there are more than 2 endpoints
       ELSEIF array_length(services, 1) > 2 THEN
          raise notice 'ERROR too many , service_id =%' , r.service_id;
       ELSE
          raise notice 'Value: %', r.service_id ;
          raise notice 'Value: %', services[:1];
          raise notice 'Value: %', services[2];
       END IF;
       

        end loop;
       CLOSE cur_row;
END;
$$;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need for dynamic SQL here, and `distinct` is not a function. - it always applies to all column in the SELECT list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)`  or `distinct a, b`

Comment: It is unclear what your desired output is. Do you want a list of service_id that have more than one customer? So 200 in your above example. Or a list of those service_id and the customers they belong to?

Comment: Hi, I need the pair of same service_id with the same customer_id (100,123) and (100,123) . The real table has additional columns and I have to make some calculations using both rows.

Comment: That seems to be as simple as `select service_id, array_agg(customer_id)
from services
group by service_id
having count(distinct customer_id) = 1` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5c3031868d5308cc246a2284dd840875

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hint. I used the array_agg(column_name) to get several information and work with them. I was doing something more complex than the required output.